# HTML5(or other) with M3U8 on windows

Tags: html, stream, video-streaming, html5-video, m3u8

Is it possible to get an M3U8 stream to play on windows and linux via the web browser?

I would prefer HTML5, but I don't mind if isn't.

I have read around but all I found out was that I couldn't make it work on other stuff then Mac, so is this completely true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only via third party solutions. JW player Premium and Enterprise can play HLS using flash.

Comment: Okay. There aren't any OpenSource solution to do it?

Comment: You can try the hls plugin for osmf. But I have never used it, so Im not sure how well it works.